# Is Haskell Embeddable?

Tags: haskell, embedded, embedding

I'm wanting to know if it's possible to develop applications in or on Haskell to Windows Mobile, also if there is any version of hugs or ghci for Windows Mobile. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it would be wildly inefficient, but there's no reason why it shouldn't be possible since Haskell can obviously be compiled to C. However, there's probably a better solution to achieve whatever goal it is you're after.

Comment: I already have CeGCC installed on my computer(Linux one, in Windows I have VS), but if I put ghc to point for the CE compiler instead of the default gcc it will be compiled nice?